# listening to a port on my VPS and then send to PHP MYSQL to save

Tags: php, mysql, tcp, port, vps

like listening to a port TCP on my VPS and then send to PHP MYSQL to save.

I know how to connect php to mysql, but I can not listen to port and send the LOG to php

thanks

Comment: PHP isn't really the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example of a daemon in C which is listening to specified port number. I wrote it as just a simple example to point as a possible way of solution. So, please, keep in mind that it's not something ready-to-use in production. Of course, stuff with mysql is not included.

I assume that stuff below should be done on some Linux-based OS.

After compiling:

```
gcc portd.c -o portd
```

it could be simply run as

```
./portd
```

Then you can test it by using telnet:

```
telnet localhost 8000
```

type a simple string, e.g. "test" and hit enter, then check daemon log file at /tmp/portd.log

Here is a code (portd.c):

```
/**
 * Simple daemon bind to a specified port example
 *
 * @author Mykhailo Stadnyk <mikhus@smart-ip.net>
 * @version 1.0
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DEFAULT_RUNNING_DIR "/tmp"
#define DEFAULT_PID_FILE    "/tmp/portd.pid"
#define DEFAULT_LOG_FILE    "/tmp/portd.log"
#define DEFAULI_LISTEN_PORT 8000

/**
 * Logging daemon activity
 */
void log_message( char *filename, const char *message) {
    FILE *logfile;

    logfile = fopen( filename, "a");
    if (!logfile) {
        return;
    }

    fprintf( logfile,"%s\n", message);
    fclose( logfile);
}


/**
 * Signals handler (kill -HUP `cat /tmp/portdaemon.pid`, kill `cat /tmp/portdaemon.pid`)
 */
void signal_handler( int sig) {
    switch( sig){
        case SIGHUP: {
            log_message( DEFAULT_LOG_FILE, "portd: hangup signal catched, restarting...\n");
            break;
        }
        case SIGTERM: {
            log_message( DEFAULT_LOG_FILE, "portd: terminate signal catched, terminating...\n");
            exit( 0);
            break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Daemonizing the application
 */
void daemonize( char *pidfile) {
    int i, lfp;
    char str[10];

    if (pidfile)

    if(getpid() == 1) {
        return; /* already a daemon */
    }

    i = fork();
    if (i < 0) {
        exit( 1); /* fork error */
    }
    if (i > 0) {
        printf( "Portd daemon started, PID: %d\n", i);
        exit( 0); /* parent exits */
    }

    /* child (daemon) continues */
    setsid(); /* obtain a new process group */

    for (i = getdtablesize(); i >= 0; --i) {
        close( i); /* close all descriptors */
    }

    i = open( "/dev/null", O_RDWR); dup( i); dup( i); /* handle standart I/O */

    umask(027); /* set newly created file permissions */

    chdir( DEFAULT_RUNNING_DIR); /* change running directory */
    lfp = open( pidfile, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0640);

    if (lfp < 0) {
        exit( 1); /* can not open */
    }

    if (lockf( lfp, F_TLOCK,0) < 0) {
        exit( 0); /* can not lock */
    }

    /* first instance continues */
    sprintf( str,"%d\n",getpid());

    write( lfp, str, strlen( str)); /* record pid to lockfile */

    signal( SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN); /* ignore child */
    signal( SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN); /* ignore tty signals */
    signal( SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
    signal( SIGTTIN, SIG_IGN);
    signal( SIGHUP,  signal_handler); /* catch hangup signal */
    signal( SIGTERM, signal_handler); /* catch kill signal */
}

void error( const char *msg) {
    log_message( DEFAULT_LOG_FILE, msg);
    perror( msg);
    exit( 1);
}

int listen_socket( int portno) {
     int sockfd;
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

     if (sockfd < 0) {
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     }

     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof( serv_addr));

     serv_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port        = htons( portno);

     if (bind( sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
         error("ERROR on binding");
     }

     listen( sockfd,5);

     return sockfd;
}

// main programm code
int main( int argc, char **argv) {
    // starting daemon
    daemonize( (char*) DEFAULT_PID_FILE);

    // bind to port (listen the specific port on all network interfaces)
    int sock_listen = listen_socket( DEFAULI_LISTEN_PORT);

    while (1) {
        // create read/write socket for client
        int sock_client;
        socklen_t clilen;
        struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;

        clilen = sizeof( cli_addr);
        sock_client = accept( sock_listen, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

        if (sock_client < 0) {
            // nobody connected?
            sleep( 1);
            continue;
        }

        // read buffer
        char buffer[256];
        bzero( buffer, 256);

        // read the data from socket to buffer
        if (read( sock_client, buffer, 255) < 0) {
            // client was connected but we failed to read the message from him
            log_message( DEFAULT_LOG_FILE, "Can not read data from client!");
            close( sock_client);
            continue;
        }

        // Voila! client connected - data recieved and saved to buffer variable
        // now we can do something with data from client
        // here we just put data in a logfile and close the connection
        log_message( DEFAULT_LOG_FILE, (char *) buffer);
        close( sock_client);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to work with mysql & data parsing in C as one of possible solutions you could call some external script from daemon process which could be written in PHP/Perl/Python/Shell etc.

Comment: Perfect .... I made some adjustments and I have apparently already 60% of the work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As afuzzyllama said PHP is not the best tool to do this. But if there is no choice for you except using PHP you need to write a daemon and use sockets to bind a daemon to listen an appropriate TCP port. [Google](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?rlz=1C1SKPL_enUA408UA408&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&rlz=1C1SKPL_enUA408UA408&sclient=psy-ab&q=create%20php%20daemon&oq=create%20php%20daemon&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=5984l7092l0l7503l7l7l0l0l0l0l123l658l5.2l7l0&gs_l=serp.3..0.5984l7092l0l7503l7l7l0l0l0l0l123l658l5j2l7l0.frgbld&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=43e7b3983c4556bc&biw=1440&bih=775&ix=seb&ion=1) will provide you a lot of information how to write a daemon in PHP.

Comment: If PHP is not the best option .... as I can listen to the port and stored in MySql?

Comment: Not very clear what the task you want to solve. But if it looks like you tell just "listen a port for data and sore it to mysql" I'd preffer to write some daemon in C or C++. But as I said I don't know whole the context of your task so which technology to choose or how to implement is an open question

Comment: I have a GPS that send this to a port

$ $ z129, 354660046834688, AAA, 35,4.000000, -74.000000,120306064134, A, 3,11,2,72,3.1,2606,1241165,1333258

I need to capture and store in MySql

Comment: OK, now it clear. Yeap, you need a daemon which will listen a port. As said before - you can choose any technology to implement it. Even PHP. But from my personal experience PHP-daemons are not stable, had problems with memory leakage, etc. Thus, you can choose anything. As for me - I vote for daemon in plain C :)